# why array size information is available to `sizeof` operator and delete[] operator, but not when passing array as an argument into function

Tags: c++, arrays

I was wondering how `sizeof` operator and `delete[]` got to know the actual size of the array they are operating on, but when I pass an array as an argument to functions, that size information is lost and the size information needs to be passed into the function explicitly by the programmer?

What is the internal mechanism that resulted in this discrepancy?

```
#include <iostream>

void my_function(int* p, int n) {
    std::cout << "when passed into a function as argument, array size information is not available" << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    std::cout << "sizeof(a): " << sizeof(a) << std::endl; // size information available to `sizeof` operator

    int* b = new int[3] {1, 2, 3};
    delete[] b; //size information available to `delete[]` operator

    int c[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    my_function(c, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that the "size information is available" in the case of the `b` pointer in your code? It may (must) be available *internally* to the system's memory allocator, but try showing some code where you can fetch the size of the `b` array *solely* from the pointer itself (like if you pass *that* pointer to another function).

Comment: I may have not made my point entirely clear, when using `delete[]`, the array size information is not available to the programmer, but it is available to `delete[]`, that's how `delete[]` can deallocate memory assigned to the array, right?

Comment: Yes! Just as it would be in the case of a pointer returned by `malloc` (which may even be used to implement the `new[]` operator). To your C++ code, it's just an address; to the system, it is an address that is somewhere/somehow indexed into a system-wide memory manager's list of allocated blocks.

Comment: so the size information is available to the `delete[]` operator, but why can't that same information be made available for arrays passed in as an argument to a function?

Comment: It's *not* available to the `delete[]` operator. It is available to the system-specific *implementation* of that operator. A pointer in C++ is ***just*** an address. Passing  such a pointer to a function does not convey any information to that function about the size of the data block, whether that pointer is from `new[]`, `malloc` or the address of a fixed, user-declared array. It is *still* just a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the `delete[]` operator knows how much memory is associated with a particular pointer value is because it has a copy of that value saved in its internal data structure that was written when `new[]` was used.  From strictly a language standpoint, it doesn't know how much memory a pointer points to.

There's also a requirement that a pointer pass to `delete[]` **must** have been returned by `new[]`.  Passing in any other pointer value results in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The `sizeof` operator only looks at the type of its operand and is thus evaluated at compile time.  In your code, the `sizeof` operator can see that its operand has type `int[3]` and evaluates to the size in bytes of the array (12 on most systems).

When you pass an array to a function, it *decays* to a pointer to the first element of the array.  So in `my_function` you only have a pointer.  You could have just as easily done something like this:

```
int x;
my_function(&x, 1);
```

So if you were to use `sizeof` on the parameter `p` it looks at the type of the operand which is `int *` and evaluate to the size of the pointer (most likely either 4 or 8).

Comment: Just wondering, why can't they make the "copy of that value saved in its internal data structure" available to programmer?

Comment: @Thor Depending on the library, it may be available.  On Linux, there's a function called `malloc_usable_size` that returns the number of bytes a malloc'ed pointer points to.  Stuff like is very system specific, however.

Comment: @Thor Loose pronouns lose understanding. ;) When you wrote that comment, did you have a clear picture of who "they" are? In this context, there is a huge difference between "they" meaning the people writing C++ specs and "they" meaning the people implementing C++ on a particular system.